# How to get a copy of drawable android.R.alert_light_frame?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-resources

I'm using an Android drawable called android.R.alert_light_frame as a background for an element in my UI. I got the idea from some sample code I found. I like the effect of this drawable, but the frame margins are a little larger than I'd like so I want to edit the bitmap.

But I can't find this drawable anywhere in the SDK. I've looked in the paths recommended here for all the versions of the SDK I've downloaded, and the file definitely isn't there. I've searched my entire hard drive with a couple of different search products and there's no file with that name.

The drawable loads into my app and I can see the resource ID when I look under Android 4.3 in Eclipse, so it must be compiled into the library. I believe this drawable was added back in API 1, so maybe they stopped shipping the source bitmap.

Can anyone tell me where I can find it? It's not in any of the Google icon downloads. Is there a way to extract it from an apk or jar file?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame` (notice the added `drawable`)?

Answer (score 3):

The resources can be found in the platforms folder of android-sdk, e.g.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res